# How to do copy/paste function programmatically in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, copy-paste

I have a text-view with some text and a copy button in that view,

When the user enters some text and presses the copy button, it needs to copy that text and paste that text wherever he wants.

I know there is a default copy/paste menu-controller in iOS, but I want to do this functionality in a button click. I think there is `UIPasteboard` to do this functionality, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To copy from a button click:

```
- (IBAction)copy {
    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pb setString:[textView text]];
}
```

To paste from a button click:

```
- (IBAction)paste {
    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    textView.text = [pb string];
}
```

Comment: Only part of the text is selected in the text view. How can copy and paste only selected instead of copying whole thing.

Comment: This will work if you are happy to always replace the existing contents of the textview. If you want to paste at the cursor position this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 24):

## Swift

This is the Swift version of the accepted answer.

**Copy**

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = myTextView.text
```

**Paste**

```
if let myString = UIPasteboard.general.string {
    myTextView.insertText(myString)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For developers using MonoTouch, here are the two lines I used to complete the task in C#.

The answer iscavenger provided to this question served as the model for my answer (after I successfully implemented it in my project ;-)

```
UIPasteboard clipboard = UIPasteboard.General;
clipboard.String =  "string being added to clipboard";
```

Comment: There is no big sense in declaring explicit variable clipboard. Would be twice shorter if you inline UIPasteboard.General :)

Comment: was explicit for example sake... but I too love one-liners.  ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why we can't simply use:

```
[theTextView paste:nil];
```

as per [UIResponder docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/paste:)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you can relatively easily do what you want, starting with the [`[UIPasteboard dataForPasteboardType:]` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPasteboard/dataForPasteboardType%3a).

There's Apple sample code you can look into at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CopyPasteTile/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009040

Comment: Add in some code into your original question that shows how you are firing a button action and then taking the data from the pasteboard using the `[UIPasteboard dataForPasteboardType:]` method. If it still doesn't work for you, I can try to edit my answer to show you how it will work.

Comment: i put this in my code but after taping the copy button the app crashes,-(IBAction)_clickbtncopynotes:(id)sender
{
    [UIPasteboard dataForPasteboardType:textView.text];
}

Comment: That's not the way to call the code (it's just a standard way to describe the likely method you would be using). You'd probably need to do something like `textView.text = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] dataForPasteboardType: @"public.utf8-plain-text "]`. Please take a good look at the sample from Apple that I pointed you to and see how they retrieve data from the pasteboard.

Comment: Please check my comment for previous answer and try to answer it