# app-specific UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipasteboard

I'm trying to create app-specific UIPasteboard, but have some problems figuring out how to register it:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"myPasteboard" create:YES];
```

If I just create it, app continues to use generalPasteboard. I really hope that I don't have to catch cut/copy/paste operations and set items manually.

Comment: How are you copying and pasting items in the pasteboard ?

Comment: I need it to work with UITextFields. When user selects and copies text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this article
http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/ (It's about UILabel, not UITextField but is useful just for example and information about how copy/paste/edit actions work and how you can customize its' behavior)

I think you need to subclass `UITextField` to `MyTextField` for example, and override `-(void)copy:` and `-(void)paste:` methods from `UIResponderStandardEditActions`.

In your implementation of these methods you should use your custom `UIPasteboard` to copy text into and paste from it, like mentioned in this answer,

[How to do copy/paste function programmatically in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045970/how-to-do-copy-paste-function-programmatically-in-iphone)

but instead of using `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]` use `[UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"myPasteboard" create:YES]`

Comment: You can also swizzle them without calling the original selector

Comment: @Swizzle? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Copy your text field text and Just App in Pasteboard
NSString * text=textfield.text;
UIPasteboard * pasteboard=[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setString:text];
```

Below is a Tutorial about Pasteboard.
http://hayageek.com/uipasteboard-example-read-write-share/

Answer (score 0):

```
//pasteboard initialization
let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.general

// copying the content of textview to pasteboard
if(pasteBoard.hasStrings){
   pasteBoard.string = textViewPB.text
}

//pasting the content of pasteboard to textview
if(pasteBoard.hasStrings){
   textViewPB.text = pasteBoard.string
}
```